# Allure Report: How to show Test Name Value From TestNG Suite XML File On Report?

Tags: testng, allure

In TestNG framework, we use testng suite xml file to define the tests and call mvn (with -Dtestset=testng.xml) to execute them. In side of the xml file, we have test tag with name value, but this name value does not seem to appear anywhere in Allure report. Is there a way to make it to show on the Allure report (prefer to be in the same place as @Feature annotation)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite For Debug Run" verbose="10" configfailurepolicy="continue">
<test verbose="10" name="Debug Run" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.someTestClassName">
            <methods>
                <include name="someTests"/>
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Relates to https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/issues/312.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to give some answer to this question I can state that right now you can solve this problem by implementing your own Allure adapter as described in the Github issue I mentioned above. However this will probably be supported in some of 1.4.x releases.